# What caused the blue column of ionised air above Chernobyl exploded reactor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, ionization-energy

I read that the blue column of light directly above the exploded reactor was actually the ionisation of air but I like to know where did the electric field came from to cause such phenomenon? I imagine thunder cloud where there is a built up of electric potential and then a lightning occurs so for the column of blue light there must also be a electric potential and why column that extends into the sky?

Comment: Ionizing radiations?

Comment: Cherenkov radiation, which is not particularly related to ionization?

Comment: I doubt it. Air refractive index is about $1+3.10^{⁻4}$ ; if my math are correct that means $γ\simeq$ 40 for a particle reaching speed of light in air. For beta particles (lightest charged particles) that's about 20MeV, a bit high for nuclear decay. Works for cosmic rays though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Air glows when molecules, that are brought to an excited state by a collision, go back to a less-excited state by emitting a photon.

The question becomes : what generated a particle fast enough to generate such a collision?

- Acceleration of a charged particle by some electric field. That's the case for lightning or neon lights, for example.
- Emission of an energetic particle by some high-energy process (such as radioactive decay) ; this doesnt need any electric field. As far as I know, that was the case for Chernobyl : nuclear reactions in the core sent high energy particles in all directions ; those that went down or sideways were stopped by concrete in meters (or less) but those going upwards could travel through air (which is less dense) for a bit, eventually hit some air molecule and bring it to an excited state in the process. 
  The fact that the light-column was kilometers high indicates that the mean-free-path of those high energy particles was kilometers (at least). That strongly suggests γ-ray photons.

I have read several times that this glow was due to Cherenkov radiation (light emission by charged particles going through a medium faster than light propagation). I have some doubts about it because light speed in air is so close to that in vacuum (refractive index is very near 1) ; therefore the energy needed for a particle to be above the speed of light in air is positively huge, higher I think than energy of most nuclear processes. On the other hand, particle energy necessary to bring a molecule to an excited state would be mere eVs, much lower than that of any nuclear process. (obviously, blue glow of water in a nuclear reactor is an other matter, since speed of light in water is significantly slower than in vacuum, enabling Cherenkov radiation much more readily)

Comment: I agree. Here is an image how an intense x-ray beam from a synchrotron makes the air glow: https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/introduction-4/

Answer (score 2):

To enlarge slightly upon Nicolas' answer: an energetic beam of particles can indeed create that blue glow in air. For example, a 1.5 MeV electron beam dumped into air will produce a blue glow extending up to 15 or 20 inches from the beam aperture. The glow is released by recombination in the ions that the e-beam creates. Generous amounts of ozone will be produced in the process which will severely corrode any steel or iron parts in the vicinity.

Comment: …or lungs, for that matter !